# Alternatives to Varnish for Windows Server

Tags: windows, nginx, cygwin, varnish, squid

My OS is Win2003 server (64bit) and I want some software to do file caching. Varnish or Nginx's cache on Windows is based on Cygwin (32bit) and its size is limited to only 2GB, which is too small for me. Are there any alternatives I can use on Windows?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to run it on Windows? You really should have a dedicated server for a solution like this.

Comment: @BillyONeal For the file server is already on windows for many years, and now its storage will be moved from hard disk to Cloud Storage, so I want to build a local web server to handle cache and request from cloud, and the old system gets data from the local web server directly.

Comment: @BillyONeal Uhm, Windows 2003 Server *is often* used as a [dedicate] server .. sort of sounds like use-case here.

Comment: @pst: Yes, I know that. What I'm saying is -- caching solutions like Squid, Varnish and HAProxy are designed to run on dedicated boxes, on which nothing else is running. If you are running a machine dedicated to that purpose, there's no reason not to install a Unix-y operating system on such a machine. If you need to run this kind of thing on a server with other things running, you've mostly defeated the point of a caching server. If you must use something like this I would at least recommend running the cache in its own VM.

Comment: @BillyONeal I do not find that logic productive. Given a Windows Server box, there is no need to install a Unix-y operating system. Yeah, "Open Source is Awesome", but that's no reason to switch from a perfectly good Windows Server install. And no, using Windows Server isn't "defeating" the point of a caching server nor is running multiple services on a machine. Before making such statements the setup/bottlenecks should be analyzed. While VMs are *awesome* (and, like SSD, I never want to go back), they are an *orthogonal* issue and only add [a small] overhead - even with modern virtualization.

Comment: Could you do fragment caching in your web application with Memcache? I think that will run on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There are versions of Squid and Nginx that will run on windows without Cygwin